# How to count the number of turtles in a cluster - netLogo

Tags: cluster-computing, netlogo, turtle-graphics

I have a population of turtles that are programmed to cluster/merge (code below). I want to have it that once a cluster reaches a certain size (my-groupSize) the cluster hatches new turtles. It seems that the mygroupSize is counting the number of ticks not the number of turtles in the cluster. How would I keep track of the number of turtles in a cluster?

```
 ask origs [
    let candidates origs in-radius 1 with [leader != [leader] of myself]
    if any? candidates [
      create-links-with candidates [ hide-link ]
      ask candidates [ merge ]
    ]
    set my-groupSize my-groupSize + 1.0
  ]
  tick
end

to merge  ;; node procedure
  ;; First this node merges.
  set leader [leader] of myself
  set heading [heading] of leader
  set color blue
  ask link-neighbors with [leader != [leader] of myself]
    [ merge ]
    set my-groupSize my-groupSize + 1.0
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If my-group-size is a turtles-own procedure, then each turtle has its own version of that variable. So when each turtle adds 1, it is adding 1 to its own version of that variable. It doesn't count up across all turtles in the group.

Instead, use only the leader's version of my-group-size. When a turtle is merged, do:

```
ask leader [ set my-group-size my-group-size + 1 ]
```

Then any agent can get to the group size with `[ group-size ] of leader`

This assumes that leaders aren't also losing members. In that case, once all leader changes are made, you might need to gather the leaders into a set (if not already well known), then ask them to count their followers.

```
;; get leaders
let all-leaders turtle-set ([leaders] of turtles )
;; count group sizes
ask all-leaders [ set my-group-size count turtle with [ leader = myself ] ]
```

I do not know enough of your model to suggest any less brute-force methods. But they are out there.

If you don't already, then you might want to initialize `leader` to 'self`. This way, you can always refer to leader, even for turtles not following another turtle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering this @TurtleZero I wonder when all leaders are called and their followers counted, won't that include leaders who are just leaders of themselves and outside the cluster?